# Emacs Chrome key bindings

Tags: google-chrome, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

There are many addons and bindings to have program **X** behave like emacs, e.g. Qt Creator has an emacs key bindings mode, Chrome has some add-ins and other stuff to have emacs key bindings altogether.. my question is the reverse:

I find Chrome's key bindings extremely logical

```
Ctrl + F == Find here
Ctrl + T == Tab
Ctrl + F4 == Reminds me of Alt + F4 used to close an app.. and it works for tabs
```

and so on.

Is there any way to have **emacs** work with Chrome key bindings?

Comment: Decide which keys you want to mimic. Decide what the analogous emacs command is for each one. Decide how you want to deal with conflicts with standard keys. Bind commands to keys in the normal ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [CUA mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode) (CUA - Common User Access), whose key bindings will be similar to Windows users, and I guess Chrome users as well.